# Map method for multiple indexed array values for react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

- I used first index filtered array value results and rendered them based on different criteria
- I am struck how to use map all the index values of the filtered array values and render it on UI
- can you guys help me to solve issue with your suggestions
- The entire code is available in the stackblitz and its link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-geum6v?file=index.js
- code snippet for one user filtered value and tried multiple index array values are been provided below:
- can you let me know where I did mistake in execution multiple indexed array values for the map method

index.js (JS part)

```
sportsZipSearch = () => {
    const { zip1, dob1, age1, state1, check, count } = this.state;

    const newArray = students.filter((el) => { return ((el.zip === zip1) && (parseInt(el.Age) <= parseInt(age1[Object.keys(age1)[0]])) || (el.sports_state != (state1)) && check ) });
    const newArray1 = newArray[0].Sports_games.map((el1) => { return Object.keys(el1) });
    //const sorted = newArray1[Object.keys(newArray1)].sort();
    console.log(age1);
    console.log(zip1);
    console.log("here--", this.state.zip1, this.state.age1);
    console.log(newArray);
    console.log(newArray1);
    //console.log(sorted);
    console.log(newArray.Subjects);
    console.log(count);
    this.setState({ result: newArray, zipValue: true })
  }
```

index.js (html part)

```
Show list Sports: {result.length && result[0].Sports_games.map(g => { var visibility = (check && g[Object.keys(g)[0]]) ? 'block' : 'none'; return <div style={{display: visibility}}>{Object.keys(g)[0]} {g[Object.keys(g)[0]]}</div> } )}<br/><br/>

Show list Sports: {result.map(result_new => result_new.length && result_new.Sports_games.map(g => { var visibility = (check && g[Object.keys(g)]) ? 'block' : 'none'; console.log(visibility);return <div style={{display: visibility}}>{Object.keys(g)} {g[Object.keys(g)]}</div> } ))}<br/><br/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a component that takes these values in its props and display them, and then use map to convert the data array to an array of components. And then put that in whatever container element that you want.

Like this:

```
function MyComponent() {
    return (
        <div>
            <p>{props.data.name}</p>
            <p>{props.data.age}</p>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Then you map the data array to component array:

```
my_component_array = my_data_array.map(d => <MyComponent data={d} />);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help...the code is working...one clarification...can we able more than one value from parent to child component and mapped to props...say for instance, {zipValue && <Zip result={result} grade1={grade1}/>} and mapped to props under Zip component

Comment: Yes you can pass any number of props that you want

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply...when passing the value grade to props from parent to child component and accessing as props.grade in the child component, its throwing error...can you provide your suggestion...hope it helps for my future reference